# Splitting tabular across rows

Tags: tables

I'm aware of the `cline` command within `tabular` to only draw a line between two columns.

Is there an (easy) equivalent for vertical lines? (across rows?)

I am aware of the `multirow` package, but I think this solution is particularly tedious and doesn't really allow for the nice tables I expect from LaTeX.

Comment: You mention "nice tables"... then you should forego the use of vertical rules. Read the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf): "(1) Never, ever use vertical rules; (2) Never use double rules."

Comment: That's a pretty poor excuse for excluding the functionality. I'm using a typesetting program to have control over *whatever* I can think of. By this argument I could stop right here and migrate to Microsoft Word. :/

Comment: That's not the point. Either way, when you start trying to have control over *everything*, then for sure you're run into things that are tedious and things that are not. You can't just have your cake *and* eat it... You're specifically talking about rules, correct? Horizontal rules are adjustable in terms of their column visibility via `\cline`. For vertical rules, you have to use a re-specification of the cell via `\multicolumn{.}{<spec>}{..}`.

Comment: Also why does the multirow package not allow for nice tables?

Comment: Because this code will make you chuckle: `\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[h]{c | c | c | c}
& & & \\
$i$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$1$ & $2$ & $3$} \\
& & &\\
\hline 
& & &\\
$f_i$ & $18$ & $14$ & $9$  \\
& & &\\
\hline
& & &\\
$e_i$ & $12,3$ & $11$ & $6,5$  \\
& & &\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}`

Comment: This code can't compile… So what?

Comment: it's much better to edit the question and use the `{}` button to format code rather than putting code in comments (and please make it a _complete_ document that shows the problem)